# Angular. Ui-router и права доступа до шаблона

Tags: angularjs, доступ, шаблоны, ui-router

Подключил Ui-router. Отображает три разных шаблона в разных местах. На сервер отправляем некий параметр (он же stateParams) по которому возвращается `true` или `false`. Как добавить и куда эту проверку, чтобы по результату с сервера отображало нужные шаблоны или выводило шаблон с информацией про недоступность шаблона? Если `false` все три шаблона должны быть недоступны. 
Пробовал в лоб решать прописывая проверку в templateUrl, не работает и дублировать для 3-х шаблонов явно не правильно.

```
.config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider', function($locationProvider,$stateProvider,$http){
        $stateProvider
            .state('page', {
                url: "/page:page",
                views: {
                    "viewVideo": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                            $http({
                                url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',
                                method: "POST",
                                data: $.param({order: stateParams.page}),
                            })
                                .success(function (response) {
                                    if(response) return '/index_'+ stateParams.page+'_video.html'
                                })
                        },
                        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
                    },
                    "viewText": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                           $http({
                                url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',
                                method: "POST",
                                data: $.param({order: stateParams.page}),
                            })
                                .success(function (response) {
                                    if(response) return '/index_'+ stateParams.page+'_text.html'
                                })
                        },
                        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
                    },
                    "viewQuiz": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                            $http({
                                url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',
                                method: "POST",
                                data: $.param({order: stateParams.page}),
                            })
                                .success(function (response) {
                                    if(response) return '/index_'+ stateParams.page+'_quiz.html'
                                })
                        },
                        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
}]);
```

Хотел использовать решения задачи вот такой способ

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .run([
        '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
        function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    if (true) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    ]);
```

Но как в `if` впихнуть ajax запрос через $http не имею представления. Кто простенький пример покажет с Resolve для моей проблемы? Нужно перед загрузкой шаблона проверять что возвращает $http аякс запрос

http://plnkr.co/edit/oILOiXh8iGxoxzT1Xe2j?p=preview

Возник другой вопрос. Для уменьшения нагрузки на сервер данные будут извлекаться из модели pageData, инициализация которой будет происходить при первой загрузки страницы:

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .run([
    '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams','$http',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http) {

        $http({
            url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param({lecture: idLecture}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
        })
            .success(function (response) {
                $rootScope.pageData = response;
            })
```

Потом чтобы не обращаться к серверу при изменении ссылки каждый раз(кроме тех случаях когда модель будет меняться) хотелось бы проверять некое значение из этой модели. Если например `$rootScope.pageData[0].isDone==true` загружаем тэмплейт

```
 templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                        if ($rootScope.pageData[0].isDone==true)
                        return '/video.html'
                    },
```

Это тоже решается через resolve или есть что-то элементарнее? А то `$rootScope` использовать в `$stateProvider` не получается

Comment: посмотри [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: не могу разобраться с этим resolve(

Comment: можешь пример, например на plunkr, привести как сейчас работает?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oILOiXh8iGxoxzT1Xe2j?p=preview - вот приблизительно накинул.Теперь нужно перед отображением обращаться аяксом на сервер и в зависимости от результата отображать то что есть либо(если запрос вернет false) шаблон с предупреждением о том что пользователь не имеет права для просмотра

Comment: ага, добавьте эту ссылку в пост тоже

Comment: а ограничение на весь стейт или на каждый вью должна быть проверка?

Comment: Обновил ответ, и открыл чат :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [свойством resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

> Это свойство - объект, содержащий пары ключ-значение:
>
> ключ – {строка}: название зависимости, которая будет внедрена в контроллер.
> значение - {строка|функция}:
>
> - если строка - алиас для сервиса.
> - если функция - будет внедрено значение функции. Если функция возвращает *Promise*, то он будет разрешен до создания контроллера, а значение будет внедрено в контроллер. Если возвращаемый *Promise* перейдет в статус *rejected* - будет послано событие `$stateChangeError`

Подписавшись на это событие и проверив ошибку - можно выполнять необходимые действия по обработке.

Применительно к вашему случаю: `$http` сервис возвращает *Promise*, поэтому его можно перенести в свойство *resolve*

```
.state('page', {
    url: "/page:page",
    resolve: {
        auth: function($q, $http){
            return $http({
                        url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',
                        method: "POST",
                        data: $.param({order: stateParams.page}),
                    })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        if(response) return "authorized";
                        
                        return $q.reject('not authorized');
                    });
       }
   },
   ....
```

Теперь, в случае, когда запрос вернет *true* все покажется и если прописать в контроллере

```
function lessonPageCtrl(auth, .../*другие внедрения $scope и т.д.*/) {
    console.log(auth); //authorized
```

в случае, если запрос вернет *false*, переводим результат в состояние *rejected* и ловим в обработчике [*$stateChangeError*](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-state-change-events)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        console.log(error); // not authorized
    }
);
```

[**Пример использования**](http://plnkr.co/edit/B0QVurquV4ItSPowIIbS?p=preview)

[**Пример с $http**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EF8gu4Cy3x4bgmO6S1SW?p=preview), в *data.json* - значение.

**Замечание**
Вы назначаете один и тот же контроллер трем разным *view*, в данном случае будет создано три объекта контроллера, которые будут не связаны между собой.

Comment: Буду разбираться завтра. Возник другой вопрос, добавил к первому. Благодарен за внимание

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, другой вопрос лучше отдельно, например со ссылкой на этот, а то запутаться можно что где и куда, да и объем большой уже

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471148/angularjs-ui-router-rootscope-%D0%B2-templateurl спс, добавил

Comment: С чем может быть связано что  console.log(auth); выводиться при любых условиях обьект Object {data: "myResponse", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}. Даже если $http прописать   .success(function (response) {
                                return $q.reject('not authorized');
                            }). не реагирует на то что написано в success

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, нужно конкретно пример кода смотреть, вы смотрели планкер из моего ответа? там выводится все корректно?

Comment: да там. корректно, проблема когда использую сервис $http. Частично решил вопрос, заменил success на .then  resolve: {auth:function ($q, $http) { return $http({url: basePath + '/lesson/GetPageData',method: "POST",
                            data: $.param({lecture: idLecture}),
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'} }).then(function(response){ if(response.data!=0) return "authorized"; return $q.reject('not authorized');});}},  Кажется так работает, только $q.reject('not authorized'); в консоль не выводится

Comment: *.then(function(response){
                            if(response.data!=0) return "authorized";

                            return $q.reject('not authorized');
                        });

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, код все-таки лучше либо в plunkr, либо хотя бы в пост - чтобы форматирование было :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32394/discussion-between-grundy-and--).