# AngularJS. Ui-router. $rootScope в templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, шаблоны

Есть модель `$rootScope.test`, которая заполняется при инициализации странички в `.run`

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .run([
    '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams','$http',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http) {
        $rootScope.test = true;
    }
])
```

Хочу использовать эту модель, ее  значение в функции которая выводит `templateURL` в `$stateProvider UI-router`

```
$stateProvider
          .state('page', {
               url: "/page:page",
              views: {
                    "viewVideo": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams,$rootScope){
                          if($rootScope.test == true)
                            return 'indexV'+ stateParams.page+'.html';
                            else return 'indexT'+ stateParams.page+'.html';
                        },
                        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
                    },
```

Но этой модели не видно в `templateURL`

В зависимости от значения модели нужно вывести тот или инной шаблон, как это сделать?

[Нерабочая версия](http://plnkr.co/edit/oILOiXh8iGxoxzT1Xe2j?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/oILOiXh8iGxoxzT1Xe2j?p=preview - рабочая версия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *ui-router*, свойство `templateUrl` является то ли *String*, то ли *function*. Когда это *function*, функции передаётся только один параметр — `$stateParams`. Тут [документация](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider). Поэтому, в следующем коде `$rootScope` будет всегда `undefined`:

```
views: {
    'viewVideo': {
         templateUrl: function (stateParams, $rootScope) {
             // $rootScope undefined
         },
         controller: '...'
    }
```

В принципе, можете внедрить `$rootScope` в *config* функцию, но вас это не поможет, так как `$rootScope.test` пишется в *run* блок, то есть *после* конфигурации.

Один способ решить проблему — подписываться на `$stateChangeStart` и тут поменять `templateUrl` в зависимости от значения `$rootScope.test`:

```
angular.module(...)
    .run(function ($rootScope){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
            if (toState.name === 'viewVideo') {
                toState.templateUrl = $rootScope.test ? '...' : '...';
            }
        });
    }
```

Но это скорее всего *hack*. Судя по описанию, Вам вроде нужны два состояния, и в зависимости от значения `test`, звать то или иное состояние. Да и таким образом *test* остаётся в своём контроллере, что позволяет уберечь `$rootScope` от загрязнения.